# How to configurate mysql server (up speed)

Tags: mysql

I have a database size 13.4Gb. The server has 32 GB of RAM.

But the query type select are still very slow.

I started the mysqltuner and he issued the following message:

```
-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 5s (9 q [1.800 qps], 7 conn, TX: 17K, RX: 1K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 100% / 0%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Total buffers: 24.5G global + 392.4M per thread (64 max threads)
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 24.9G (79.27% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 49.0G (156.10% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/9)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 1% (1/64)
[!!] Aborted connections: 14.29%  (1/7)
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 4 selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (0 on disk / 2 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 85% (1 created / 7 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 93% (100 open / 107 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (15/1M)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (100 immediate / 100 locks)
-------- InnoDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 23.4G/13.4G
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 24
[!!] InnoDB Used buffer: 0.03% (414 used/ 1535976 total)
[!!] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 79.34% (1463 hits/ 1844 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write buffer efficiency: 0.00% (0 hits/ 1 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 2 writes)
```

I have the following server mysql configuration:

```
key_buffer_size = 1024M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
read_buffer_size = 8M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 128M
thread_stack = 128K
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 8M
query_cache_type = 1
thread_cache_size = 16
max_heap_table_size = 128M
tmp_table_size = 64M
net_read_timeout = 3600
net_write_timeout = 3600
wait_timeout = 120
interactive_timeout = 120
table_open_cache = 1024M
#join_buffer_size=2048M
max_connections        = 64
innodb_open_files = 4096
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=24000M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=24
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size = 500M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
#innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_read_io_threads = 8
innodb_write_io_threads = 8
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0
#innodb_io_capacity=2000
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
```

Could you please tell me how to correctly correct the following errors and increase the speed of sampling from the database?

```
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 24
[!!] InnoDB Used buffer: 0.03% (414 used/ 1535976 total)
[!!] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 79.34% (1463 hits/ 1844 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write buffer efficiency: 0.00% (0 hits/ 1 total)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 49.0G (156.10% of installed RAM)
[!!] Aborted connections: 14.29%  (1/7)
```

P.S. I do not use indexing because it increases the query timeout and increases the size of the database.

Comment: What do you mean by that indices will increase the query timeout? Maybe you are doing something wrong with your indices.

Comment: @Progman I mean, if I use indexes, the database size will grow to 100gb

Comment: There is ALWAYS a trade-off between time and space - if you need faster SELECT queries then you have to use indexes. If you need faster INSERT/UPDATE queries then you have to get rid of all indexes except primary keys. If you need minimal storage - you have to cache some hot parts of your data into RAM. You simply can not have both at the same time.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I understanding you correctly, if I need the speed of sampling from the database, should I sacrifice disk space? But what do I do with the fact that RAM will also require the cost to process the request?

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear enough: (1) SELECT will be faster if there is a proper index in the table compared to if there is no suitable index to use. (2) In the same time INSERT/UPDATE will be slower if there is an index compared to when there is no index.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Do you want to say that you need to sacrifice space on disk and memory in order to speed up the request as much as sending the request or configuring the server?

Comment: @AlexStorm If you do not have an index on your table - it does not matter how fast is your CPU or how many IOPS your disk storage system can achieve, or whether your RAM clock is 1866 MHz or 2400 Mhz. Because MySQL will always scan your entire table if there is no index. You can tune your Linux as much as you possibly can - but simply adding an index (or more, depending on your case) will improve the speed of SELECT by order(s) of magnitude. Answering your question - you ALWAYS have to sacrifice something. Currently you are sacrificing the speed in the sake of less disk space.

Comment: @WilsonHauck 1. This is full config. 2. [GLOBAL STATUS](https://pastebin.com/raw/NxCTim8z) 3.[GLOBAL VARIABLES](https://pastebin.com/raw/mZvgdrLa)

Comment: @IVOGELOV Probably you are right, can you look at this? So you will understand what I'm talking about.
For example, my [simple query](https://pastebin.com/raw/VNa8X7vq) I created all the necessary indexes to execute this query, but it does not work.

Comment: The query is simple. I need to select all buyers who made purchases for the specified period of time and bought a certain type of goods in some stores (if specified), while the buyer has an email, phone and they are women.
To create such a query, I have to combine several tables, otherwise it does not work out.

Comment: And in the future I will need to group the received data, because there can be duplicated.

Comment: I assume you understand the difference between OLTP and OLAP databases ? While OLTP are highly normalized, OLAP are often (and sometimes heavily) denormalized and indexed - all to speed-up the analytics. For your simple query - try not to join by `card_new` and look at the EXPLAIN. When the column `key` is NULL - either you really need all the records from the given table or you do not have an appropriate index. I would highly recommend the book "SQL tuning" by Dan Tow, ISBN 0-596-00573-3 - it will really help you.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Yes, of course I know what is their main difference and here I use the OLTP, because I also have a large amount of data insertion. I thank you for this recommendation, I will definitely study this book!

Comment: @AlexStorm The original config listed in the Question is far different than the GLOBAL VARIABLES that came from your system.  I will list just 3 of them in detail, 1) KEY_BUFFER_SIZE 1024M is 16M, 2) MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET 1024M is ~530K, 3) READ_BUFFER_SIZE 8M is 128K.  At least 8 more are different than indicated.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck I did not notice that the configuration does not connect to the file.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I have globally studied the issue of query acceleration, and decided to completely abandon the use of large table joins by breaking them into small logical subqueries.
And I added indexes. This helped speed up the current request up to 2 minutes. But the database has grown almost 5 times (

Answer (score 1):

I'll probably leave here all the useful answers that helped me solve this problem.

1. Always verify that the specified server configuration values are correct
2. If you need fast type requests - select, you need to sacrifice the size of the disk.
3. The correct database structure will avoid complex queries and increase performance.
4. It is necessary to try to perform small logical queries not large and not logical.
5. The configuration of the server does not greatly affect the speed of the request, if the request is not correct.
6. Ideally, should use hashes, not indexes)
7. In the new version of the muscle, try to use more often - WITH table as (SELECT)
8. Read a book - "SQL tuning" by Dan Tow, ISBN 0-596-00573-3

I can not single out one particular piece of advice that helped me, because they are all good.

Comment: Keep in mind that hashes are prone to collisions - unlike indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf or my.ini [mysqld] section

```
max_connections=500  # from 1000 to conserve RAM - only 3 were used on this day
thread_cache_size=100  # from 16384 V8 indicated to CAP at 100 
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K  # from ~512K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS
innodb_adaptive_hash_index=ON  # from OFF to minimize deadlocks
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct=90  # from 25 for more WARM data at startup
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8  # from 24 will be sufficient and conserve CPU
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=10  # from 30 to reduce loop delay
innodb_lru_scan_depth=128  # from 1024 to conserve CPU every second
innodb_page_cleaners=8  # from 24 for same as number of pool_instances 
innodb_read_io_threads=64  # from 4 see dba.stackexchange Question 5666 9/12/11 entry
innodb_write_io_threads=64  # from 4 explained by RolandoMySQLDBA in Q 5666
innodb_thread_concurrency=0  # from 4 also explained by Rolando
open_files_limit=30000  # from ~1 Million - for a reasonable limit
query_cache_limit=0  # conserve RAM since QC is NOT being USED - and that is GOOD
```

for additional assistance, view my profile, Network Profile for contact info, including Skype ID and get in touch, please.

Please keep us aware of your progress, in a few days/weeks.

Comment: @Alex Storm  Are you making any progress?  Keep us posted, or get in touch with me, please, as requested above.